# Find four integers summing to zero, with sum of cubes 24

Tags: polynomials, diophantine-equations, factoring

I'm stuck on the following problem from Terence Tao's "Solving Mathematical Problems"

> Find all integers $a,b,c,d$ such that $a+b+c+d=0$ and $a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3=24$. (Hint: it is not hard to guess *some* solutions ti these equations, but to show that you have *all* of them, substitute the first equation into the second and factorize.)

---

**My attempt:**

After said substitution, I now want to solve

$$-3 a^2 b-3 a^2 c-3 a b^2-6 a b c-3 a c^2-3 b^2 c-3 b c^2-24=0 $$
by factoring the LHS. There is some evident symmetry, so I tried going with $c=Aa+Bb+C$ for one of the factors without success. Moreover, Mathematica can't seem to factorize this polynomial as well.

I'd appreciate any help on this problem, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide by $-3$ of your expression, we have

$$a^2 b+ a^2 c+ a b^2+2 a b c+ a c^2+ b^2 c+ b c^2+8=0 $$

Note that

$$\begin{split}(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) &= (ab+ac + b^2 +bc)(c+a)\\
&= abc + ac^2 + b^2c + bc^2 + a^2b + a^2 c+ ab^2 + abc \\
&= -8
\end{split}$$

As $a, b, c$ are integers, there are not many choices. You need then to solve

$$\begin{split} a + b &= \alpha \\ b+c &= \beta \\ a+c &= \gamma \end{split}$$

$$\Rightarrow a = \frac{\alpha -\beta +\gamma}{2},\ \ b = \frac{\alpha + \beta - \gamma}{2},\ \ c = \frac{-\alpha + \beta + \gamma}{2}. $$

where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are any integers so that $\alpha\beta\gamma = -8$. Now you need only to check which choices of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ would make $a, b, c$ integers.

(To come up with that factorization, one observe that the expression is of homogeneuos degree three (except the constant term) and are highly symmetric in $a, b, c)$. Thus $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$ is more or less the first thing you want to try.)

Comment: So, one shouldn't factorize the whole thing then... Thanks! Also, could you confirm that the solutions are (up to permutations) $\{-4,-4,3,5\}$ and $\{-1,-1,-1,3\}$?